# Jenkins pdepend plugin error

Tags: php, ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-php

I am using Jenkins in Windows, when I build the project I am getting the below error on Ant task pdepend.

```
pdepend:
     [exec] Can't find the custom report class: --jdepend-chart=C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Tracking/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg
     [exec] Result: 1
```

PMD is working fine without error and getting graph in Project Dashboard page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means exactly what it says: the file could not be found at that location.

I would double check your configuration, as the following path from your error message seems wrong:

```
--jdepend-chart=C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Tracking/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg
```

Namely the backslashes becoming forward slashes halfway through the path name. With the limited information available, that appears to be your problem.